Does different way of string normaliztion effect to tokenizing phase
I have two string having Different type of normalization
# Text from source I crawled
string1 = 'Thu điếu'

# Text from my keyboard
string2 = 'Thu điếu'

print('string1:', string1.encode('utf-8'))
print('string2:', string2.encode('utf-8'))

This is the result
# NFD
string1: b'Thu \xc4\x91i\xc3\xaa\xcc\x81u'

# NFC
string2: b'Thu \xc4\x91i\xe1\xba\xbfu'

My question is, does this effect any natural language model or even the tokenizing phase of LLM
